# Search for and connect to a local server (C-programming)

Tags: c, sockets, find

I'm doing some socket programming in C where I have one server and many clients on the local network. I want the client to find (search for) the server on the network by itself (i.e.not having to specify the server's address) and connect to it. The protocol between the clients and server should be TCP.

I've been searching the web for some time to find a good solution to this, but haven't found one yet.

Any suggestion to how I would tackle this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if not the ip what does he uses to identify the server

Comment: He probably means that the program will try to connect on a specific port for the whole subnet.

Comment: Yes, I should have specified that. The client should try to connect through a specific port and find a server on the subnet that is available at that port.

Answer (score 2):

An IP and port number is necessary for a client to connect to the game server. However, if the IP address of the server is not available, a 'compromise' could be reached by:

- Using a hostname to connect to the server, you can use `gethostbyname()` to resolve a hostname and obtain the IP address. This should solve the issue if the server's IP is not known or is not static.
- Having a process running on a *known* IP which can give you a list of active servers.
- Having the clients scan a particular *range* of IP addresses instead of trying to connect to a *single* IP (not a very good idea, but should be doable on a LAN).
- Havinh your server broadcast packets (say UDP datagrams) at fixed intervals to all hosts on the current subnet (again not really a good idea, will lead to unnecessary network traffic).

A hybrid approach with more than one of the above could also employed, for example, try connecting via a hostname and if that fails, fallback to connecting to a *known* IP with list of active servers etc.

Comment: Instead of having the server broadcast continually, you could have the client broadcast to the subnet that it wants to know where the server is. But having a hostname seems simpler :)

Comment: @gnud: Yes, similar to DHCP. I guess this would be better than the server flooding the subnet with UDP datagrams.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the network layout and such, I would use a solution involving DHCP and DNS.

Basically, you want to connect your DHCP server to your DNS server so that it would automatically create entries for new computers on the network. This is a feature that most DHCP servers and DNS servers support, including BIND and `named` and Microsoft's solution.

Then you'll set the server hostname to some known value, and have the clients find the server using DNS. That is, `gethostbyname()` would work properly so you could use the first bullet point offered in Bhargav's answer.